# Limit result set in sql window function

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

Assume I would like to rewrite the following aggregate query

```
select id, max(hittime)
from status
group by id
```

using an aggregate windowing function like

```
select id, max(hittime) over(partition by id order by hittime desc) from status
```

How can I specify, that I am only interested in the first result within the partition?

EDIT: I was thinking that there might be a solution with [ RANGE | ROWS ] BETWEEN frame_start AND frame_end. What to get not only max(hittime) but also the second, third ...

Comment: What do you mean with "first result"? There is only one maximum hittime per partition.

Comment: this window query will return me the whole table, when I am only interested in the max result. Distinct, as suggested by @amirreza-keshavarz helps in this case.

Comment: What i can't see why you don't want to use the `GROUP BY`. And both your second query and Amirezza's have a redundant `order by hittime desc`

Comment: My question may not have been specific enough. The GROUP BY works without problems, but what to do when I want eg. max and the second largest?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think what you need is a ranking function, either ROW_NUMBER or DENSE_RANK depending on how you want to handle ties.

```
select id, hittime
from (
     select id, hittime,
            dense_rank() over(partition by id order by hittime desc) as ranking
     from status
     ) as x
where ranking = 1;  --to get max hittime
--where ranking <=2;  --max and second largest
```

Answer (score 2):

Use distinct statement.

```
select DISTINCT id, max(hittime) over(partition by id order by hittime desc) from status
```